# Mysterious Memory Leak in Cocos2D Project

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, cocos2d-iphone

I'm leaking memory when I call the following code. I've tried the obvious (releasing the object after I'm done with it, and returning an autoreleased object) but I get the following error:

> [CCTouchJoint release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1dd10f30

*In main loop:*

```
CCTouchJoint *tj = [CCTouchJoint touch:touch withMouseJoint:mouseJoint];
[touchJointList addObject:tj];

[touchJointsHaveNotMoved addObject:tj];
//*If I add [tj release] here we crash
```

*In CCTouchJoint.h*

```
@interface CCTouchJoint : NSObject
{
@public
    b2MouseJoint *mouseJoint;
    UITouch *touch;
}
@property (assign) b2MouseJoint *mouseJoint;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITouch *touch;
```

*In CCTouchJoint.mm*

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [touch release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (id)initLocal:(UITouch *)_touch withMouseJoint:(b2MouseJoint *)_mouseJoint
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        self.touch = _touch;
        mouseJoint = _mouseJoint;
    }
    return self;
}

+ (id)touch:(UITouch *)_touch withMouseJoint:(b2MouseJoint *)_mouseJoint
{
    return [[self alloc] initLocal:_touch withMouseJoint:_mouseJoint];
   //*If I return an autoreleased object here we crash
}

- (void)destroyTouchJoint
{
    if (mouseJoint != NULL)
    {
        mouseJoint->GetBodyA()->GetWorld()->DestroyJoint(mouseJoint);
    }
}
```

*On level quit or restart*

```
-(void)removeAllTouchjoints:(BOOL)release{
    //remove touchjoints
    for (CCTouchJoint *tj in touchJointList)
    {
        [tj destroyTouchJoint];
    }

    for (CCTouchJoint *tj in touchJointsHaveNotMoved)
    {
        [tj destroyTouchJoint];
    }

    [touchJointList             removeAllObjects];
    [touchJointsHaveNotMoved    removeAllObjects];

}
```

Comment: Note:  You're not "leaking" memory, you're referencing a released object -- pretty much the exact opposite.

Comment: Note that `[CCTouchJoint touch:touch withMouseJoint:mouseJoint]` should begin with "new" or one of the other special prefixes if it's returning a retained object.

Comment: Have you tried running Analyzer?

Comment: Have you tried removing the two properties and using iVars exclusively in this class?  The two are kind of redundant and it may be causing problems with the _(underscore) notation you are using in your methods.  It doesn't appear that you are accessing the properties from outside the class anyways.

Answer (score 0):

In your init method you use the setter (self.touch =...), which you shouldn't do.
Assign to the iVar and retain directly.

what is the crash (exception message) when you return an autoreleased object or add a release to the other method?

**EDIT**

Ok, I cant reproduce your error using the code you gave. So it must be somewhere else in the class. What is the error message?

**EDIT 2**

What if, instead of

```
CCTouchJoint *tj = [CCTouchJoint touch:touch withMouseJoint:mouseJoint];
[touchJointList addObject:tj];

[touchJointsHaveNotMoved addObject:tj];
//*If I add [tj release] here we crash
```

you do

```
CCTouchJoint *tj = [CCTouchJoint alloc] initLocal: touch withMouseJoint:mouseJoint];
[touchJointList addObject:tj];

[touchJointsHaveNotMoved addObject:tj];
[tj release]; //does it crash here?? What message?
```

Comment: Hi Mario, thanks for your answer. I've added the error message, which only shows when I autorelease or release the returned touchjoint. My problem isn't the error so much as it is the leak; I'm leaking CCTouchJoints everytime I touch an object.

Comment: Well, it is leaking because you comment out the release/autorelease. Question is, why cant you return an autoreleased object (using the same code you gave, I have no problem doing so)

Comment: EDIT 2: produces the same error message as the autorelease method.

Comment: strange. then maybe something wrong with your mutableArrays...?

Comment: Note that we've just assumed that they're NSMutableArrays.  We don't have the declarations or allocations to check that assumption.